# How to figure out size of Indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to determine the size of my indexes, they are primary key indexes. This happens to be on mysql cluster but I don't think that is significant.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
show table status from [dbname]
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Comment: Avg_row_length, Data_length, Max_data_length, Index_length, Data_free are all reported in bytes, yes.

Comment: This gives the *total* index size, not a size per index (assuming a table has multiple indices).

Answer (score 140):

Extending Vajk Hermecz's answer.
This is how you can get all of the indexes size, in megabytes, without the PRIMARY (which is the table itself), ordered by size.

```
SELECT database_name, table_name, index_name,
ROUND(stat_value * @@innodb_page_size / 1024 / 1024, 2) size_in_mb
FROM mysql.innodb_index_stats
WHERE stat_name = 'size' AND index_name != 'PRIMARY'
ORDER BY size_in_mb DESC;
```

Answer (score 63):

If you are using InnoDB tables, you can get the size for individual indexes from `mysql.innodb_index_stats`. The 'size' stat contains the answer, in pages, so you have to multiply it by the page-size, [which is 16K by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size).

```
select database_name, table_name, index_name, stat_value*@@innodb_page_size
from mysql.innodb_index_stats where stat_name='size';
```

Comment: Fantastic. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: To clarify: With this query, the `stat_value` is already multiplied by the page-size, so the column gives the index size in bytes.

Comment: Thank you, much better than the accepted answer. A note for other noobs like me - database_name, table_name and index_name are not to be replaced with your real database name and table name ;) instead the command should be used exactly as it is.

Comment: in my case it gave a very different (and unrealistic) size from the one reported by `show table status from [dbname]`

Answer (score 11):

Here's an adaption from some of the above to also give you the percentage of the total index for the table that each index has used, hopefully this will be useful for someone

```
select 
    database_name, 
    table_name, 
    index_name, 
    round((stat_value*@@innodb_page_size)/1024/1024, 2) SizeMB, 
    round(((100/(SELECT INDEX_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = iis.table_name and t.TABLE_SCHEMA = iis.database_name))*(stat_value*@@innodb_page_size)), 2) `Percentage`
from mysql.innodb_index_stats iis 
where stat_name='size' 
and table_name = 'TargetTable'
and database_name = 'targetDB'
```

Example output

```
database_name   table_name  index_name  SizeMB  Percentage
targetDB        TargetTable id          10      55.55
targetDB        TargetTable idLookup    5       27.77
targetDB        TargetTable idTest      3       16.66
```

Regards
Liam

Comment: I have a particular case in which for a PK indexes the Percentage shows values over 100, like 1844 or 677. I guess there's a problem with the query for those cases.

Answer (score 6):

On `MyISAM`, each index block is `4 KB` page filled up to `fill_factor` with index records, each being `key length + 4` bytes long.

`Fill factor` is normally `2/3`

As for `InnoDB`, the table is always clustered on the `PRIMARY KEY`, there is no separate `PRIMARY KEY` index

Answer (score 3):

Using phpMyAdmin, when viewing the table structure there is a Details link at the bottom somewhere. Once you click on it it will show you the total size of the indexes you have on the table where it is marked Space Usage.

I don't think it shows you each index individually though.

Comment: With phpMyAdmin that's really easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[From the MySQL 5.6 reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html)

```
SELECT SUM(stat_value) pages, index_name,
SUM(stat_value)*@@innodb_page_size size
FROM mysql.innodb_index_stats WHERE table_name='t1'
AND stat_name = 'size' GROUP BY index_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you were looking for a "low hanging fruit" like me, here is a query to find the biggest unused indexes on MySql:

```
SELECT IDX.*, IO.stat_value FROM sys.schema_unused_indexes IDX
left join mysql.innodb_index_stats AS IO on (IO.table_name = IDX.object_name AND IO.index_name = IDX.index_name)
where IO.stat_name='size'
order by IO.stat_value DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to know how much space an existing index needs **per row**, you can have a look at the `key_len` output from the [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html) command, which shows the index size in bytes:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_1 = A AND column_2 = B;
```

If the query would return at least 1 row, this will show the size of an index on `(column_1, column_2)`. You can validate the correct index was used in the `key` column of the output.