# MYSQL database design, queries between large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-performance

### What I have:

`tableA` with ~250 million rows like:

```
A_id     thing_id     thing            
----     --------     -----
001      345          foo
002      567          bar
003      678          poo
004      789          gar
```

AND

`tableB` with ~50 million rows like:

```
B_id     thing_id     user_id     action            
----     --------     -------     -----
001      123          001         some
002      234          002         thing
003      345          001         dont
004      567          002         matter
```

*Now:* `thing_id` can only be in `tableB` one time

*Later:*  I need the ability to have multiple `thing_id`'s from different `user_id`'s in `tableB`

### What I need to do:

*Now:* Select a `thing_id` from `tableA` that is NOT already in `tableB`

*Later:* Select a `thing_id` from `tableA` that is in `tableB` less than X times

Self taught in SQL and I can't find a way to do this efficiently with very large tables. Maybe I just don't have indexes right? I have been testing with MariaDB if that makes a difference.

**

### EDIT (as requested)

**

### TEST_tableA:

```
/*Table: TEST_tableA*/
----------------------

/*Column Information*/
----------------------

Field      Type         Collation    Null    Key     Default  Extra           Privileges                       Comment  
---------  -----------  -----------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  ---------
tableA_id  int(11)      (NULL)       NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references           
thing_id   int(11)      (NULL)       YES     UNI     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
thing      varchar(32)  utf8mb4_bin  YES     MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           

/*Index Information*/
---------------------

Table        Non_unique  Key_name  Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment  Index_comment  
-----------  ----------  --------  ------------  -----------  ---------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ----------  -------  ---------------
TEST_tableA           0  PRIMARY              1  tableA_id    A                97561    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
TEST_tableA           0  thing_id             1  thing_id     A                97561    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE                               
TEST_tableA           1  thing                1  thing        A                97561    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE                               

/*DDL Information*/
-------------------

CREATE TABLE `TEST_tableA` (
  `tableA_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `thing_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thing` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tableA_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `thing_id` (`thing_id`),
  KEY `thing` (`thing`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2050005 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

### TEST_tableB:

```
/*Column Information*/
----------------------

Field      Type         Collation    Null    Key     Default  Extra           Privileges                       Comment  
---------  -----------  -----------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  ---------
tableB_id  int(11)      (NULL)       NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references           
thing_id   int(11)      (NULL)       YES     MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
user_id    int(11)      (NULL)       YES     MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
action     varchar(32)  utf8mb4_bin  YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           

/*Index Information*/
---------------------

Table        Non_unique  Key_name  Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment  Index_comment  
-----------  ----------  --------  ------------  -----------  ---------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ----------  -------  ---------------
TEST_tableB           0  PRIMARY              1  tableB_id    A                25092    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
TEST_tableB           1  thing_id             1  thing_id     A                25092    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE                               
TEST_tableB           1  user_id              1  user_id      A                25092    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE                               

/*DDL Information*/
-------------------

CREATE TABLE `TEST_tableB` (
  `tableB_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `thing_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tableB_id`),
  KEY `thing_id` (`thing_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

### The query:

```
SELECT a.thing_id 
FROM TEST_tableA a
LEFT JOIN TEST_tableB b ON a.thing_id = b.thing_id
WHERE b.thing_id IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Show us please the output from **SHOW CREATE TABLE TableA** and **TableB** and also what you have tried

Comment: If something is not efficient, then presumably that something is a query.  So, what query are you trying to optimize.

Comment: @BerndBuffen updated

Comment: @GordonLinoff added query

Comment: What is the execution time of that query? In worst case you need to read 50M rows from table A before you find a thing_id that is not in table B. That can take some time.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel with a test table of 750,000 rows for tableB, query is taking 12-14 seconds :/ which is way too long.

Comment: Please also include table size (`show table status`), index size (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33292823/5563083), `select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size`, your hardware (RAM) and EXPLAIN result of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Neither table seems to need an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  It clutters the disk and slows down the queries (for tables this size).

```
CREATE TABLE `TEST_tableA` (
  `thing_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thing` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`thing_id`),
  KEY `thing` (`thing`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `TEST_tableB` (
  `thing_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`thing_id`, user_id),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

If either is really a many:many mapping table, the see my [*many:many tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Note: the PK I suggest allows for your *"Later"*

**Now: Select a thing_id from tableA that is NOT already in tableB**

```
SELECT A.thing_id
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B  ON A.thing_id = B.thing_id
    WHERE B.thing_id IS NULL;  -- meaning that it is missing from B
```

**Later: Select a thing_id from tableA that is in tableB less than X times**

```
SELECT A.thing_id
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B  ON A.thing_id = B.thing_id
    GROUP BY A.thing_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) < X ;
```

I think both of these will involve a full table scan of A, with probes into B.

(Hint:  Don't clutter you table or column names with unnecessary prefixes.)

Comment: The problem is I can't afford to do a full table scan on each query as I need to do this query A LOT.

So maybe I need find another table set up.

Comment: Is `LIMIT 1` part of the question now?  That changes things.

Comment: That changes things? I didn't think it would. Yeah I am grabbing 1 at a time.

Comment: Is there also an `OFFSET`?  That is even more critical.  Please don't "simplify" the problem; we end up answering the wrong question.